# Checking proof that $f(x)=x^2+1$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2+1$.  Prove this function is continuous for all $x \in\mathbb R$.

Here is what I have:

Suppose that $c∈ℝ$.  Let $\varepsilon>0$.  Let $\varepsilon=\delta$.  Then

$$
\begin{align}
& |f(x)-f(c)|=|x^2+1-(c^2+1)| \\[6pt]
= {} & |x^2-c^2| \\[6pt]
= {} & |x-c|^2 \\[6pt]
= {} & |x-c|< \sqrt{\varepsilon}
\end{align}
$$

Then

$$|f(x)-f(c)|<(\sqrt{\varepsilon})^2=\varepsilon$$

Thus, proved.

Comment: $|x^2-c^2| \neq |x-c|^2$. Same way $|x-c|^2 \neq |x-c|$.

Comment: As an aesthetic point, you shouldn't write something like "Let $\epsilon = \delta$" when $\delta$ itself has not been defined.  It's preferable to write "Let $\delta := \epsilon$" to tell the reader you're defining a new symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-c|\lt \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(c)|\lt \epsilon$.  Let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given. We produce a suitable $\delta$.

We have 
$$|f(x)-f(c)|=|x^2-c^2|=|x+c||x-c|.\tag{1}$$
We want to show that the expression on the right side of (1) can be made "small" if we take $|x-c|$ sufficiently small.

The potential "spoiler" is the term $|x+c|$, which could be large. There are two cases to consider, $c\ne 0$ and $c=0$. We leave the case $c=0$ to you , and deal with $c\ne 0$.

We want to control the size of $|x+c|$. To do this, first specify that we will pick  $\delta \le |c|/2$. If $|x-c|\le |c|/2$, then $|x+c|\le 3|c|/2$. It follows that the expression on the right of (1) is $\le \frac{3}{2}|c||x-c|$.

Thus if $\delta$ satisfies the two conditions  $0\lt \delta\le |c|/2$ and $0\lt \delta \le \frac{2}{3|c|}\epsilon$, and if $|x-c|\lt \delta$, then we will have $|f(x)-f(c)|\lt \epsilon$. It is therefore enough to let $\delta=\min(|c|/2, \frac{2}{3|c|}\epsilon)$.

For the case $c=0$ that is left to you, we need to find a $\delta$ such that if $|x|\lt \delta$ then $x^2\lt \epsilon$.